# are __m128, __m128d, __m256, etc built-in types in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, sse, avx

The C++ standards distinguish between built-in types and `struct` or `class` types. For the latter it is allowed to overload operators, such as `+`, `*=`, or `&`, but not for built-in types, when the appropriate operators are provided by the language. AFAIK, the SSE/AVX types are not mentioned in the standard (but please correct me), so one should be able to declare these operators. GCC does not allow that, but ICC does. Which one is correct?

I really would like to have the bit-wise operations (like `&=`), but, annoyingly, GCC does not provide them (for `__m128`) nor does it allow me to declare them.

Comment: Are you sure? Bitwise `__m128i & __m128i` works perfectly fine at least since gcc-4.4. It is even documented in the onlinedocs.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz yes, **but** *1* the `&` and `&=` are only defined for `__m128i` and not for `__m128`. *2* If I only have SSE (and not SSE2), it is not defined, but the intrinsic `_mm_and_ps(__m128,__m128)` still is. So IMHO, there should be operators `&` and `&=` for `__m128` implemented using that intrinsic. btw, I like your handle -- will use Hirschhornsalz for making Honigkuchen at the weekend

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All are correct. These types are extensions to C++, not built in (almost nothing built into C++ begins with underscores). Since they are extensions, the implementation is free to impose any restrictions on them it wants.

Answer (score 6):

They're not built-in. C++ isn't dependent on specific HW architecture features.

Comment: I don't think the question is whether they can be called *built-in* (which is not a technical term from the standard) as much as whether overloading operators on those types should be allowed. Note that you can also interpret *built-in* (not being a term from the standard) as *built-in the compiler*, in which case they might actually be built-in (or not, they might be defined in some header)